# Can connect via command line but not via a PHP script

Tags: php, amazon-rds

We upgraded our Amazon RDS instance and the application could not connect to the new one. We tried to SSH into the app server and then connected fine via the command line. We made a simple one line php script that connects with the same credentials and from both the webserver and PHP client it just hanged and then gave an error that it could not connect. We are sure that the hostname resolves the the correct IP address from the app server and we have dropped all security groups. Any ideas?

Comment: As a first debug step: set up a database on another machine that's visible on the Internet and of which you have complete control and try connecting to that both via CL and your PHP script. Watch where the requests are coming from.

Comment: Please provide important details, i.e. the *exact*: (1) command that succeeded, (2) php cli script that failed, (3) entire error message (obviously strip out username/password).

Answer (score 0):

Are you using RSA security keys to access the server? Keep in mind the php app, running as the apache user will have a different RSA key to the user to run the command line as - you'll need to add that key to the remote server too.